# How to keep plus number in loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, numbers

I want to keep adding number in very loop or in one times it hard to explain like when the code keep going from the top the the end and my plus variable also plus the number from 1 to higher.

```
]while True:
    plus = 0
    name = input('Name:')
    print(name)
    plus += 1
    print(plus)
```

Answer (score 0):

A general notes:

- Firstly, remember about indentations. The body of a loop has to be  <s>4 spaces</s>  indented (EDIT: of course, it can be any number of spaces, as long as it is more than in the block level higher).
- Secondly, if you set while loop condition as True, the loop will run forever and I assume it's not your aim. If you really want to keep that "True" condition at the begining, remember always to set a "break" condition inside the loop.

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly - you mean, that you want to get input of sequential string values (name), print that names in loop, and print which time it is - am I right?

Then the solution is:

```
plus = 0  # start value must be before the loop, in your example you set "plus" variable on 0 at the begining of each iteration


while True:

    plus += 1

    name = input('Name:')
    print(name)

    print(plus)
    if plus >= 20 or name == 'Caroline':  # here write your contition to preserve the loop from infinite execution
        break
```

Comment: "The body of a loop has to be 4 spaces indented." Not true. It can be indented any number of spaces as you like, as long as that number is more than the block one level higher.